# Wordpress shows additional category text

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, categories

I am developing WP website and stuck in side bar category showing functionality.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="sidebarcategory"> 
        <h2 class="widgettitle"><?php echo get_cat_name(3); ?></h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <?php wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name&child_of=3&feed_image=http://devsites.dyndns.info/novelty/wp-content/themes/pixel/images/icon-car.png'); ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So, this display me Additional "Category" over the top of the list which i don't require. Can anybody help me to remove out in dynamic code. Output looks like

```
<ul>
            <li>
            </li><li class="categories">Categories<ul>  <li class="cat-item cat-item-4">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a emty parameter title_li

```
wp_list_categories('title_li=&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&child_of=3&feed_image=http://devsites.dyndns.info/novelty/wp-content/themes/pixel/images/icon-car.png');
```